# How to check if time changed manually in C#

Tags: c#, winapi

I am writing a program that does something on computer periodically based on current time. But user may change windows time manually and make my program confounded.
My idea was saving current time in every loop iteration and comparing it with last saved time. So I could determine time changing and the amount of change. But it makes mistakes. System Hibernate (and Sleep) does same thing so I can't make difference between "manually time changing" and "System Hibernate".
In fact Now the problem can be solved with determining Hibernate (and Sleep).
Can you please help me (In determining Hibernate (and Sleep) or determining time changing)?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [`Stopwatch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to measure elapsed time. The stopwatch does not depend on the system clock and is therefore not affected by changes to it.

Hibernation, sleep etc. can be detected with the [`SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.powermodechanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event.

Comment: Yes, Stopwatch measures elapsed time. But it does not measure the time system is sleep (or Hibernated). So like before I can't do my job based on current time (sleep time affects current time but does not affect stopwatch) and I can't make difference between sleep (or hibernating) and time changing.

Comment: And about `SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged`, I used that but my program did not change. I don't know why but this event did not call assigned function. Can you guess why?

Answer (score 0):

Use time web services to check the time on application startup.
Or you can create Windows service that will check for time change even if your program isn't launched.